# What modules do I need to add tokens in my content that references the current nodes field?

Tags: 7, tokens

I have a blog content type and I also have a taxonomy reference field for "color". How do I embed the field's color value in the body of my blog post via a token?

Comment: Please don't add tags to the title. The most used tag is already going to be added to the title shown in the `<head>` tag. This means that the title of this page is "**7** - What modules do I need to add tokens in my content that references the current nodes field? - Drupal Answers."

Answer (score 0):

You'll need...

- [Entity API](https://drupal.org/project/entity) for its extended entity/field token support
- [Token filter](https://drupal.org/project/token_filter) which provides a simple filter that supports tokens

And probably nothing else :)

Comment: seems that there might be an issue with performance since the token filter doesnt cache: https://drupal.org/node/2055307

Comment: That makes sense - as Dave Reid put it in that issue: _What happens if you add "Copyright (c) [current-date:year]" into a footer block text on Dec 31?_